# cannot resolve transaction.add(R.id.watch_video_player, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

Tags: android

> Cannot resolve the method
>   add(int,com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment)

I want to add a youtube player in main activity also use with another fragment too.

```
 YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.fragment, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
       youTubePlayerFragment.initialize("KEY", new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onInitializationSuccess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //load and play the video with current id
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo("S88M5nTXJak");
                youTubePlayer.play();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing your fragment before `transaction.add(...)`